# "Android R" getPackageInfo("mypackage",0) is throwing PackageManager.NameNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-source

I have tried the following source code in the 'Android R' emulator, and it is throwing `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException`.

```java
getPackageInfo("com.mycompany.mypackage",0);
```

Is anybody facing the same issue ? Any idea if this API will be deprecated, if some extra permissions are required starting from 'Android R', or if it is a simple issue in the emulator ?

Comment: This might be a package visibility issue. See [this](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility) and [this](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility-use-cases) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on CommonsWare answer, I have added

```xml
<queries>
   <package android:name="com.mycompany.mypackage" />
</queries>
```

To the Android manifest file, and the issue has gone.